# Missing sets in Venn Diagram using `ggvenn` in `R`

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have a list with 7 sets of data. The following code

```
genes <- paste("gene",1:1000,sep="")
x <- list(
   A = sample(genes,300), 
   B = sample(genes,525), 
   C = sample(genes,440),
   D = sample(genes,350),
   E = sample(genes,100),
   EE = sample(genes,120),
   G = sample(genes,102))

library(ggvenn)
ggvenn(x,  stroke_size = 0.5, set_name_size = 4)
```

produces the Venn Diagram of them, but I obtained only 4 sets in the resulting plot:

[image]

How do I get the Venn Diagram of all the sets? Moreover, I would like the elements that are inside each set to be listed (for example the first ten elements of each set, since there are many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw your diagram use `venn::venn(x)` from the *venn* package. However, to obtain the elements inside use `attributes(gplots::venn(x, show.plot = FALSE))$intersections` from the *gplots* package.

[image: venn]

If you are only interested in the first 10 elements, this would work: `sapply(attributes(gplots::venn(x, show.plot = FALSE))$intersections, function(x) x[1:10])`